# Creating an php array elements nested

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I am trying to create an php array elements to be nested.

For example:

I have this array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Example 1"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Example 2"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Example 3"
}
```

and I want the output to be like

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Example 1"
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(9) "Example 2"
                  array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(9) "Example 3"
                    }
```

I tried with foreach() but without success. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your output doesn't appear to make sense--there is an array and a string floating in space for each element. Do you want each element to have a single named array or a string next to an array? If the latter, should that be index `0` and `1` respectively or use some named keys? Also, when you say "output", do you actually want to transform the input array or just display it nested temporarily? Please confirm.

Comment: It would be ideal if you could show both the input and desired output arrays as actual PHP code.

Comment: can you show us how your data are represented within a php array before the output like you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $array = array("Example 1","Example 2","Example 3");



        $x = count($array) - 1;
        $temp = array();
        for($i = $x; $i >= 0; $i--)
        {
            $temp = array($array[$i] => $temp);
        }
        echo'<pre>';
        print_r($temp);

    Array
(
    [Example 1] => Array
        (
            [Example 2] => Array
                (
                    [Example 3] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```